# How to fix InvalidCastException for dynamic object?

Tags: c#, dynamic, ironruby, .net

```
ScriptEngine rubyEngine;
//...
dynamic execution_result = rubyEngine.Execute(script, scope);

if (execution_result != null && !silent)
    WriteResponce(execution_result.ToString());
```

This code generates **InvalidCastException**:

> Unable to cast object of type 'SOMELIB.Graphics' to type
>   'SOMELIB.Object'.

When the comparison occurs:

> execution_result != null

If this comparison is removed, then execution_result.ToString() throws the same exception.

I have found a workaround:

```
if (execution_result is SOMELIB.Graphics)
{
    SOMELIB.Graphics g = execution_result as SOMELIB.Graphics;
    WriteResponce(g.ToString());
    return;
}
```

but I don't understand why does this exception appear and how to fix it.

Comment: Hmm, odd that it tries to cast to SOMELIB.Object instead of System.Object

Comment: Correct. The problem is with dynamic type. ToString() works if I cast dynamic to object type: object execution_result_obj = execution_result as object;

Answer (score 0):

Cast the dynamic to object to avoid the DLR (dynamic language runtime) try bind the ToString method to its (real) dynamic class type.

```
ScriptEngine rubyEngine;
//...
dynamic execution_result = rubyEngine.Execute(script, scope);

object result = execution_result as object;
if (result != null && !silent)
    WriteResponce(result.ToString());
```